# Changed value in textbox returning wrong values

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers, return, invalidation

[image: This is my problem]

```
 private void P1STRtextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Convert.ToInt32(P1STRtextbox.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have enter a number larger than your remaining stat points!");
        }           
        else
        {
            P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text = (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].TotalStatPoints - Convert.ToInt32(P1STRtextbox.Text)).ToString();
        }
    }
    private void P1DEXtextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(P1DEXtextbox.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have enter a number larger than your remaining stat points!");
        }
        else
        {
            P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text = (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].TotalStatPoints - Convert.ToInt32(P1DEXtextbox.Text)).ToString();
        }
    }
```

So basicly the event is triggered when the text in the box is changed. When I input a number into the strength text box at first, it does the deductions properly, but when I go to the Dexterity box and try to edit the value, it does not do the deduction properly. As you can see in the picture(remaining stat points) that 3000-(250+750) != 2250;  Can someone please give me some logical advice? Thank you for your time and effort in advance!

Answer (score 2):

How about changing you P1DEXtextbox_TextChanged else statement to use the below?

```
P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text = (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].TotalStatPoints - (Convert.ToInt32(P1STRtextbox.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(P1DEXtextbox.Text))).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never adding the strength and dexterity values. You need to take both fields into account when changing the remaining stats value:

```
int strength = Convert.ToInt32(P1STRtextbox.Text);
int dexterity = Convert.ToInt32(P1DEXtextbox.Text);
P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text = (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].TotalStatPoints - (strength + dexterity)).ToString();
```

You also have to make sure that you handle possible errors when converting text to an integer.